# Does Hive joins accept equality operator such as less than symbol

Tags: hive

I am trying to match these two tables only if the  grp_id_num from left side table is falling in between the beg_group and end_group of right side table

```
+-------------+--+
| grp_id_num  |
+-------------+--+
| XA0001      |
+-------------+--+



 +---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------
 | detail_lookup.beg_group  | detail_lookup.end_group  | detail_lookup.agent  
 +---------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| XA0000                    | XZ9999                    | Exchange              | 
| WW9988                    | WW9988                    | DEVINE ETHIER         | 
| P00001                    | P99999                    | SHOP                  | 
| 002359                    | 002359                    | LG                    |
```

**My Select query :**

```
select a.grp_id_num,b.beg_group,b.end_group,b.fundtype  from 
(select codesetkey  as grp_id_num from codedetail limit 10)a
left outer join
detail_lookup b
on(a.grp_id_num >= b.beg_group and a.grp_id_num <= b.end_group)
```

**Error :**

```
 Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 5:3 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'beg_group' (state=42000,code=10017)
```

**Expected result :**

```
 XA0001 , XA0000  ,XZ9999,Exchange
```

Can some one help me on hive 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Hive only supports equi joins,

Can you try the below query.

```
WITH res1 AS 
( 
         SELECT   codesetkey AS grp_id_num 
         FROM     codedetail 
         ORDER BY codesetkey limit 10 -- adding order by to get the first set of 10 records 
), res2 AS 
( 
       SELECT a.grp_id_num, 
              b.beg_group, 
              b.end_group, 
              b.fundtype 
       FROM   res1 a, 
              codedetail b 
       WHERE  a.grp_id_num >= b.beg_group 
       AND    a.grp_id_num <= b.end_group) 
SELECT          codesetkey, 
                NULL, 
                , 
                NULL, 
                NULL 
FROM            res1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN res2 
ON              res1.codesetkey=res2.grp_id_num 
WHERE           res2.grp_id_num IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   res2
```